# Holonomy as a right adjoint, monodromy as a left adjoint

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, monodromy, holonomy, lie-groupoids

[This question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/95939/69037) about the difference between holonomy and monodromy has an interesting [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/96061/69037) by Ronnie Brown.

An excerpt:

> So holonomy comes out as a kind of right adjoint, and monodromy as a kind of left adjoint, which explains one difference.

I tried looking into the suggested references, but I failed to see the big picture.

**Question.** What is the correct setting for the excerpt? Precisely how are the holonomy and monodromy functors defined, and what are they adjoint to?

Comment: What I can guess from a fast reading of https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0110064.pdf is that holonomy and monodromy are functors from locally Lie groupoids to Lie groupoids and that the functor they are adjoint to is restriction to a nhbhd of the identity: see theorem 2.1 in the above ref and Theorem B of https://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/brownmucuk1CTGDC_1995__36_4_345_0.pdf

Comment: @NicolaCiccoli thank you for your comment..  That was useful... :)